# How to create new column in Pandas dataframe where each row is product of previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame `dt`:

```
  a
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

How do I create a a new column where each row is a function of previous rows?

For instance, say the formula is:

```
B_row(t) = A_row(t-1)+A_row(t-2)+3
```

Such that:

```
  a b
0 1 /
1 2 /
2 3 6
3 4  8
4 5 10
```

Also, I hear a lot about the fact that we mustn't loop through rows in Pandas', however it seems to me that I should go at it by looping through each row and creating a sort of recursive loop - as I would do in regular Python.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cumprod`:

```
dt['b'] = dt['a'].cumprod()
```

Output:

```
   a    b
0  1    1
1  2    2
2  3    6
3  4   24
4  5  120
```

Comment: Hi enke, thank you. As mentioned, it needs to be a function, not a simple product. I changed my question so as to better highlight this

Comment: @Snowmate then maybe use `shift`: `df['a'].shift() + df['a'].shift(2) + 3`